# Multiplying two matrices using Aparapi - not working in 3D range

Tags: java, matrix, aparapi

Currently working on a Java library for matrix operations and ML.
I use Aparapi to utilize the GPU.

I've written this code to multiply two matrices:

```
   public static NDmatrix matMul(float[][] a, float[][] b) {
        int[] aDim = new int[]{a.length, a[0].length};
        int[] bDim = new int[]{b.length, b[0].length};
        if(aDim[1] == bDim[0]){

            int[] Dim = new int[]{aDim[0], bDim[1]};
            int aVSize = aDim[0] * aDim[1];
            float[] aVector = new float[aVSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < aDim[0]; i++)
                System.arraycopy(a[i], 0, aVector, i * aDim[1], aDim[1]);
            int bVSize = bDim[0] * bDim[1];
            float[] bVector = new float[bVSize];
            for(int i = 0; i < bDim[0]; i++)
                System.arraycopy(b[i], 0, bVector, i * bDim[1], bDim[1]);
            int resVSize = Dim[0] * Dim[1];
            float[] resVector = new float[resVSize];
            int d[] = new int[]{aDim[1]};
            Kernel mKernel = new Kernel() {
                final int ht = Dim[0];
                final int wt = Dim[1];
                final int dpt = d[0];

                public void run() {
                    int c = getGlobalId(0);
                    int r = getGlobalId(1);
                    int l = getGlobalId(2);
                    localBarrier();
                    //for(int l = 0; l < dpt; l++)
                    resVector[r * wt + c] = resVector[r * wt + c] + aVector[r * dpt + l] * bVector[l * wt + c];
                }
            };
            mKernel.setExplicit(true);
            mKernel.put(aVector);
            mKernel.put(bVector);
            mKernel.put(resVector);
            mKernel.put(Dim);
            mKernel.put(d);
            mKernel.execute(Range.create3D(Dim[1], Dim[0], d[0]));
            //mKernel.execute(Range.create2D(Dim[1], Dim[0]));
            mKernel.get(resVector);
            mKernel.dispose();
            return new NDmatrix(Dim, resVector, null);
        }
        System.out.println("The number of columns in left matrix and number of rows in right matrix do not match.");
        System.out.println();
        return null;
    }
```

However, it looks like resVector[some_index] only gets updated once.
If, instead, I use a 2D range and a loop(the commented bits in the code), it works correctly.
What could be the reason for such behavior and how can I force it to work fully parallel?

Interestingly, I tried one thing that "worked" - after updating resVector[some_index], I called this.put(resVector).
However, it then couldn't compile in OpenCL and ended up using Java's multi-threading instead, eventually resulting in a correct result.

Comment: Of something you said , "parallel" here is a link just to show you a java command-line that operates in Java !  Use  CNTRL+F in your browser when you (download - only a page) open the page and "find" the word "supposition" then a few paragraphs on is some orange text and the words export CATALINA_OPTS and you will see plenty of -x symbols. That is enabling multi core initializing in 1.8.0_202 level java   -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:ActiveProcessorCount=3 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VipRDFmIWYBoaYbzYx0G70jyMKlSBIGe/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @SamuelMarchant as far as I can see, this relies on JVM. I'm specifically trying to execute my code on GPU, that's why I'm using Aparapi. If it fails to compile an OpenCL kernel, it defaults to JVM multi-processing.

Comment: Let me make this clear - I'm not asking in general how parallelize my code(that's been taken care of), I'm asking how to make Aparapi's 3D range do what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I found a solution, be it a little crazy:

```
public static NDmatrix matMul(float[][] a, float[][] b) {
    int[] aDim = new int[]{a.length, a[0].length};
    int[] bDim = new int[]{b.length, b[0].length};
    if(aDim[1] == bDim[0]){

        int[] Dim = new int[]{aDim[0], bDim[1]};
        int aVSize = aDim[0] * aDim[1];
        float[] aVector = new float[aVSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < aDim[0]; i++)
            System.arraycopy(a[i], 0, aVector, i * aDim[1], aDim[1]);
        int bVSize = bDim[0] * bDim[1];
        float[] bVector = new float[bVSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < bDim[0]; i++)
            System.arraycopy(b[i], 0, bVector, i * bDim[1], bDim[1]);
        int resVSize = Dim[0] * Dim[1];
        float[] resVector = new float[resVSize];
        int d[] = new int[]{aDim[1]};
        return getMult(Dim, aVector, bVector, resVector, d);
    }
    System.out.println("The number of columns in left matrix and number of rows in right matrix do not match.");
    System.out.println();
    return null;
}

@NotNull
private static NDmatrix getMult(int[] Dim, float[] aVector, float[] bVector, float[] resVector, int[] d) {
    Kernel mKernel = new Kernel() {
        final int ht = Dim[0];
        final int wt = Dim[1];
        final int dpt = d[0];

        public void run() {
            int c = getGlobalId(0);
            int r = getGlobalId(1);
            int l = getGlobalId(2);
            localBarrier();
            // This is where the magic happens - without this loop the code only works for l = 0 !!!
            for(int i = 0; i < dpt; i++) // really?!
                if(i == l)               // why, oh why do I have to do this...
                    resVector[r * wt + c] += aVector[r * dpt + i] * bVector[i * wt + c];
        }
    };
    mKernel.setExplicit(true);
    mKernel.put(aVector);
    mKernel.put(bVector);
    mKernel.put(resVector);
    mKernel.put(Dim);
    mKernel.put(d);
    mKernel.execute(Range.create3D(Dim[1], Dim[0], d[0]));
    mKernel.get(resVector);
    mKernel.dispose();
    return new NDmatrix(Dim, resVector, null);
}
```

Can't believe that such a bizarre loop would somehow force it to do its thing...

Comment: Without this loop, the code would only work for l = 0 !!! Go figure...